# Sharepoint 2010 Authentication Change from Windows Based to Claims Based User Profile Sync

Tags: sharepoint-2010, active-directory, ldap, claims, sharepoint-userprofile

I have a Sharepoint 2010 application with mysites, therefore I use User profile sync service. 
I changed the authentication method from windows to claims based ( choosing forms), and made necessary updates on web.config and run the commands on powershall, so I am using LDAP.

My application works with forms based authentication now, no issues, but I can not authanticate to mysites as my user name format has changed from domain/username to

One option is to somehow map new ldap formatted user and windows ad users (do not know how??), or I need to create a new connection on the user profile sync service to connect to ad with forms authantication and import users with new format too (failed to do so, any idea what needs to be configured on domain controllers to do that? ). Although, this will cause that users would get 2 different mysites if they login with windows or forms based auth.

Any idea is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Move-SPUser command to make that work. For more info check the [MSDN Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx).